# How to sum up a selected range of rows via a condition?

Tags: pandas, datetime, range

I hope with these additional information someone could find time to help me with this new issue.

sample date here --> [file](https://gofile.io/?c=bH3t3i)

'Date as index' (datetime.date)

As I said I'm trying to select a range in a dataframe every time x is in interval [-20 -190] and create a new dataframe with a new column which is the sum of the selected rows and keep the last "encountered" date as index

*EDIT* :  The "loop" start at the first date/beginning of the df and when a value which is less than 0 or -190 is found, then sum it up and continue to find and sum it up and so on

BUT I still got values which are still in the intervall (-190, 0)

example and code below.
Thks

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('http://www.sharecsv.com/s/0525f76a07fca54717f7962d58cac692/sample_file.csv', sep = ';') 
df['Date'] = df['Date'].where(df['x'].between(-190, 0)).bfill() 
df3 = df.groupby('Date', as_index=False)['x'].sum() 
df3

##### output #####


         Date              sum
0   2019-01-01 13:48:00 -131395.21
1   2019-01-02 11:23:00 -250830.08
2   2019-01-02 11:28:00 -154.35
3   2019-01-02 12:08:00 -4706.87
4   2019-01-03 12:03:00 -260158.22
... ... ...
831 2019-09-29 09:18:00 -245939.92
832 2019-09-29 16:58:00 -0.38
833 2019-09-30 17:08:00 -129365.71
834 2019-09-30 17:13:00 -157.05
835 2019-10-01 08:58:00 -111911.98


########## expected output #############

          Date             sum
0   2019-01-01 13:48:00 -131395.21
1   2019-01-02 11:23:00 -250830.08
2   2019-01-02 12:08:00 -4706.87
3   2019-01-03 12:03:00 -260158.22
... ... ...
831 2019-09-29 09:18:00 -245939.92
832 2019-09-30 17:08:00 -129365.71
833 2019-10-01 08:58:00 -111911.98
...
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) for replace values to `NaN`s of `Date` column with back filling missing values and then aggregate `sum`, next step is filter out rows with match `range` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and last use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with cast `Series` to one column `DataFrame` by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
#range -190, 0
df['Date'] = df['Date'].where(df['x'].between(-190, 0)).bfill()
df3 = df.groupby('Date', as_index=False)['x'].sum()
df3 = df3[~df3['x'].between(-190, 0)]
df3 = df3.resample('D', on='Date')['x'].sum().to_frame()
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer but when I run the first proposed solution I still got values which are still in the intervall (-190, 0) see attached [picture](https://pasteboard.co/IJ4CSZC.png). Do you have idea about that?

Comment: @mignoncharly - Do you need sum values until range, create another group and sum?

Comment: @mignoncharly - Because if yes, then output is possible any numer, e.g. if test `x = [-1,-2,-5]` then output is `-1,-2,-5`, because all values are in range so sum separately. You can check `print (df)` after `df['Date'] = df['Date'].where(df['x'].between(-190, 0)).bfill()` for `date` values - each date create groups and if some group has only 1,2, or few values it means there are consecutive values in range (groups with 1 value) or something like `-1, 100, -2,400,500` - so it create group fro first 2 values and then group for next 3 values

Comment: "Do you need sum values until range, create another group and sum" exactly ... I mean the "loop" start at the first date/beginning of the df and when a value which is less than 0 or -190 is found, then sum it up and continue to find and sum it up and so on

Comment: @mignoncharly - Can you change data sample for some data like `-1, 4, -2,4,5` with expected output?

Comment: Sorry I didnt get your question. You mean if I should expect the same output while replacing some data with -1,4,-2,4,5?

Comment: @mignoncharly - yop, my problem is not understand what need, so ask for change data for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for see your problem, because now sample data are not nice for see your problem.

Comment: ```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Computer/Desktop/Data_Prep/Test/Cleaned_Folder/sample_file.csv', sep = ';')
df['Date'] = df['Date'].where(df['x'].between(-190, 0)).bfill()
df3 = df.groupby('Date', as_index=False)['x'].sum()

df3
```

Comment: @mignoncharly - Plase change question with data and expected output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203386/discussion-between-jezrael-and-mignoncharly).